# automatically backup files to target folder in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Say I have certain file d:\homework\week1.pdf which requires constant backup to another folder e:\backup. How can I get windows10 to automatically copy and overwrite the file week1.pdf from source folder to target folder when I make change to it? I don't want other files except week1.pdf in source folder copied.

Comment: Here are the top 7 best auto backup softwares https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/auto-backup-software.html  you can use to backup your files